# Relationship between MDL and "difficulty of learning from data"

Tags: model-selection

While trying to make sense of MDL and stochastic complexity, I found this previous question: [Measures of model complexity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2828), in which Yaroslav Bulatov defines model complexity as "how hard it is to learn from limited data."

It is not clear to me how Minimal Description Length (MDL) measures this.  What I am looking for is some sort of probability inequality (analagous to the VC upper bound) which relates the "code length" of a model with its worst case behavior on fitting data generated by itself.  If such a concrete result cannot be found in the literature, even an empirical example would be enlightening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The worst case of code length of a code induced by a probability density is just the negative log of the most unlikely event, since $L_p(x) = -\log p(x)$.

I am currently working through Peter Grünwald's book 'The MDL principle'. He defines the complexity of a model class as the log of the sum of probabilities it can assign to data.

Thus, the more different datasets a model can fit, the more complex it is.

$x^n$ here is a complete data set. $X^n$ is the set of all possible data sets of length $n$. This might seem confusing, but it is done this way wo allow non-iid data.

The formal definition goes as follows: $$COMP(\mathcal{M}) := \log \sum_{x^n \in X^n} p_{x^n}(x^n)$$

where $p_{x^n}$ is the optimal $p \in \mathcal{M}$ with regard to $x^n$.

Answer (score 1):

MDL for model selection seems to mean "choose model with lowest parametric complexity". Since parametric complexity is equal to worst case excess code length when you don't know the distribution, I bet it also gives you the number of observations needed to get close to true member of `M` in KL-divergence. Parametric complexity is a function of number of observations `n` and is given as `COMP` in bayer's answer.

Chapter 14 and chapter 7 of Grunwald's book give more details