# what is K in fourier function of R

Tags: r, time-series, fourier-transform

I am using `fourier()` function of R which has arguments x,h,K. Can any body please explain me what is 'K' in this function and what is the use of it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From which package?

Comment: It is in package 'forecast'. Here is the link -http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/forecast/docs/fourier

Comment: *K:* is the *Maximum order of Fourier [terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform)*. Alternatively, you could ask what the discrete time Fourier decomposition [is](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m267/dft.pdf).

Comment: I am trying to understand, what value should I give to K while using this function in R. Does the value of K depends on the type of data. By type, means it  is daily, weekly,monthly or yearly data. Please help me in understanding this part. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use any [feature selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) approach to find an optimal value of $k$.

Feature selection is an important subject in statistics. Explaining it is, however, outside the scope of the question and well covered elsewhere. You can find good references for this on the internet. For example consider chapter 7 of *[The Elements of Statistical Learning (2nd edition)](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/)* a very good book on the subject that also 
happens to be available for free download at the author's website (see link).

There are many tools to perform feature selection. Perhaps the simplest, most intuitive is [cross-validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1826/cross-validation-in-plain-english). In the context of the model you try to fit (discrete fourier decomposition), cross-validation can be performed as so:

```
library(forecast)
library(McSpatial)
y<-ldeaths
n<-length(y)
x<-1:n
qmax<-floor(n/2)-1
```

The `forecast` package doesn't include a tool to perform `gcv` on Fourier decomposition fit of a time series. To do that, you can use the  `fourier` function in the `McSpatial` package:

```
fit_g<-McSpatial::fourier(y~x,minq=1,maxq=qmax-1,crit="gcv")
fit_g$q
```

According to the `gcv` criterion, the optimal value of `K` (this parameter is called `q` in the `McSpatial`) for the `ldeaths` dataset is 21. Now you can re-run the Fourier decomposition of the `ldeaths` dataset with this optimal value of `K` to obtain you final fit that is a valid `forecast` object:

```
fit_f<-forecast::fourier(y,21)
```

Comment: What's"n" in qmax<-floor(n/2)-1?