# K- cross-validation

Tags: cross-validation

In Max Kuhn's Book "Applied Predictive Modeling" this is writen about K-cross validation:

> As k gets larger, the difference in size between the training set and 
>   the resampling subsets gets smaller. As this difference decreases, the
>   bias of the technique becomes smaller (i.e., the bias is smaller for k
>   = 10 than k = 5).

I understand why the bias is smaller for k=10 because we fit our model on smaller subset, so we do not generalize and in fact increasing our variance.

But I do not understand what is meant under:

> As k gets larger, the difference in size between the training set and 
>   the resampling subsets gets smaller.

If k get bigger, we will have less points in resampling subset and more point in training set. So, if k=2, and N =100, size of training set is 50 and of resampling subset is also 50. The difference in size is 0, although k =2.
If k = 4 and N=100, size of training set is 75 and of resampling subset is 25. The difference in size is 75-25= 50. So, difference increases with bigger k.

I guess I am just not understanding what is meant by size of the sets.

Comment: Related, probably not duplicate: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1826/cross-validation-in-plain-english

Comment: @Anni, I hope your confusion was cleared by the answers below. Would you mind *accepting* an answer if that's the case? If you still have doubts, let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I broke out my copy. What I believe is being said is the training set is the original data set.

**Example**

With an original data set of N = 100

k = 2

subset size = 50, difference = 50

k = 4

subset size = 75, difference = 25

k = 10

subset size = 90, difference = 10

As k increase the difference between the original data set and the cross-validation subsets becomes smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Kuhn is comparing the size of the overall (original) training set with the size of each individual **resampling subset** that are used to build the models.

You are thinking that the comparison is between the original training set with the size of each **hold-out** subset.

Let's say:

$$
n = Size \ of \ the \ training \ set
$$
$$
k = Number \ of \ folds
$$
$$
n_k = Size \ of \ each \ resampling \ subset
$$

Let's consider the example used in this book (in the same section):

[image]

In this example:
$$
k = 3
$$
$$
n= 12 
$$
$$
n_k = 8 
$$
$$
Hence, \ the \ difference: \ n \ - \ n_k = 4 
$$

Now, if we take the extreme case:
$$
k = 11
$$
$$
n= 12 
$$
$$
n_k = 11 
$$
$$
Hence, \ the \ difference: \ n \ - \ n_k = 1 
$$

Notice that $n$ would always remain the same. And as you can see, the $difference$ reduces as $k$ increases.