# Gradient boosting regression Boston housing data example

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to understand the gradient boosting regression example using the Boston housing data (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html) hoping to apply it on a different task, but I'm a novice Python user and beginner to ML. I have a general understanding of what the program is doing, but I would like to know what the following codes &/or arguments are doing:

- **Line 2**: Why do we have to shuffle the data & what is `random_state=13` doing?
- **Lines 4-6**: The train & tests variables are obvious & the brackets, i.e., subsetting of a list/dictionary, but I don't understand the significance of creating offset integers & the arguments used to create it)

```
boston = datasets.load_boston() 
X, y = shuffle(boston.data, boston.target, random_state=13)
X = X.astype(np.float32) 
offset = int(X.shape[0] * 0.9)
X_train, y_train = X[:offset], y[:offset]
X_test, y_test = X[offset:], y[offset:]
```

Comment: I see several votes to close as off topic, but I think this is about the algorithm, not the program itself, so I am voting to leave it open.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Flom for keeping this question on the board.

Answer (score 3):

This code is rolling its own train/test split, but it really should be using `train_test_split` from sklearn.

In terms of what it's doing in detail:

- The shuffle is to set up for their splitting method, they are just going to take the top 90% of the data as the train set.  In order to get a random 90% when this happens, they shuffle.
- The `random_state=13` sets a seed for the random number generator manually.  This ensures that if you run the code twice, you always get the same train / test split.
- The offset is the index that cuts the data into a 90% / 10% split.  `X.shape[0]` is the number of rows, so `0.9 * x.shape[0]` is the index that splits 90% / 10%.  It's a bit wonky, because its probably a decimal, and they are depending on it being downcast to an integer when used as an index.

Answer (score 1):

This is not intended as an answer as Matthew Drury has already provided great answers. Just to expand a little bit and provide some alternatives.

The fact that they used `offset = int(X.shape[0] * 0.9)` isn't too important. It's telling you that they are using roughly 90% for training and 10% for testing. But there are several ways to accomplish this and as others have mentioned sklearn has `train_test_split` which will create `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test` for you:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = .85)
```

Reading the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) you see that you can specify both a `test_size` and `train_test` however by default `train_test` will be the compliment of `test_size`.

Another and approach is [cross validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1826/cross-validation-in-plain-english). Here's an example in sklearn:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn import linear_model

# assuming you're performing regression
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
cv = KFold(n_splits=5)
results = {'r2':[], 'coef':[]}

for train, test in cv.split(X, y):
    clf.fit(X[train], y[train])
    prediction = clf.predict(X[test])
    r2 = r2_score(y[test], prediction)
    results['r2'].append(r2)
    results['coef'].append(clf.coef_)
```

The code above can be written in a more compact way but for clarity's sake I wrote it as it. Once all CV folds have been run you can look at the mean r2 score: `np.mean(results['r2'])`. In the example above I saved the estimates of the coeficients at each CV iteration but in a similar fashion you could save whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Line 2: `shuffle` will randomly shuffle the rows of the dataset to add randomness which is a good practice while building models. `random_state=13` ensures that the result of shuffle will remain the same if you want to shuffle the data again with the same code.

To avoid lines 4-6, you can also do the splitting of data using `train_test_split()` from `sklearn.model_selection`.
For this case:
`X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)`
where `test_size` implies the proportion of testing set with respect to the complete data size.

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short.
At present it is more of a comment than an answer by our standards. Can you expand
on it? You can also turn it into a comment.

Comment: Thanks @tuomastik for revising the original question and thereby making it more easy to follow.